# Select column by name with multiple aggregate columns after pivot with Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pivot, aggregate-functions, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to aggregate multitple columns after a pivot in Scala Spark 2.0.1:

```
scala> val df = List((1, 2, 3, None), (1, 3, 4, Some(1))).toDF("a", "b", "c", "d")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.show
+---+---+---+----+
|  a|  b|  c|   d|
+---+---+---+----+
|  1|  2|  3|null|
|  1|  3|  4|   1|
+---+---+---+----+

scala> val pivoted = df.groupBy("a").pivot("b").agg(max("c"), max("d"))
pivoted: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, 2_max(`c`): int ... 3 more fields]

scala> pivoted.show
+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  a|2_max(`c`)|2_max(`d`)|3_max(`c`)|3_max(`d`)|
+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|         3|      null|         4|         1|
+---+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I am unable to select or rename those columns so far:

```
scala> pivoted.select("3_max(`d`)")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: syntax error in attribute name: 3_max(`d`);

scala> pivoted.select("`3_max(`d`)`")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: syntax error in attribute name: `3_max(`d`)`;

scala> pivoted.select("`3_max(d)`")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`3_max(d)`' given input columns: [2_max(`c`), 3_max(`d`), a, 2_max(`d`), 3_max(`c`)];
```

There must be a simple trick here, any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug, the back ticks caused the problem. One fix here would be to remove the back ticks from the column names:

```
val pivotedNewName = pivoted.columns.foldLeft(pivoted)((df, col) => 
                             df.withColumnRenamed(col, col.replace("`", "")))
```

Now you can select by column names as normal:

```
pivotedNewName.select("2_max(c)").show
+--------+
|2_max(c)|
+--------+
|       3|
+--------+
```